# Cycle() function on a class

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.5, cycle

I would like to make use of the function cycle to rotate the players in my game. I did as it follows:

```
class Pong:
    """Summary of class here.

       Longer class information....
       Longer class information....

       """


    def __init__(self, max_score):
        self.max_score = max_score
        self.game_over = 0
        self.p1_score = 10000
        self.p2_score = 2
        self.players_list = [self.p1_score, self.p2_score]

    def play(self, ball_pos, player_pos):
        import itertools
        """" ball = 1 pixel height
            paddles = 7 pixels height

            """
        player_time = itertools.cycle(self.players_list)
        print(next(player_time))

        return ""
g = Pong(2)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
```

But my output goes only to the first element `p1_score`. Can someone help me to understand why `next()` does not work in this case and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You create the `cycle` generator each time you call `play`, you probably want to do that in your `__init__` function

Comment: You are right, thank you! @user3483203

Comment: @user3483203 can you enter that as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

this answer was provided by @user3483203  on the comments

> You create the cycle generator each time you call play, you probably
>   want to do that in your **init** function

```
 class Pong:
    """Summary of class here.

       Longer class information....
       Longer class information....

       """


    def __init__(self, max_score):
        self.max_score = max_score
        self.game_over = 0
        self.p1_score = 10000
        self.p2_score = 2
        self.players_list = [self.p1_score, self.p2_score]
        self.player_time = itertools.cycle(self.players_list)


    def play(self, ball_pos, player_pos):
        import itertools
        """" ball = 1 pixel height
            paddles = 7 pixels height

            """

        print(next(self.player_time))

        return ""
g = Pong(2)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
g.play(50,51)
```